# Javascript cell.innerHTML() displays [object HTMLDivElement]

Tags: javascript

I have:

```
var cboxHTMLString = "<input type='checkbox' class='custom-control-input'"
                        + "id='customCheck1' name=${" + check_name + "}>"
                        + "<label class='custom-control-label' for='customCheck1'>"
                        + "</label>";

    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.setAttribute("class", "custom-control custom-checkbox");
    var checkbox_div = createElementFromHTML(cboxHTMLString, div);
```

The function being called is:

```
function createElementFromHTML(htmlString, element){
    element.innerHTML = htmlString.trim();
    return element;  //.childNodes;
};
```

I then fill an object with the new key-value and other key-values I received from php/mysql:

```
var d_dict = {Select: checkbox_div};
    //iterate disease_dict and add k,v to d_dict
    for(let key in disease_dict) {
        var new_key = key;
        var new_val = disease_dict[key];
        d_dict[new_key] = new_val;
    }
```

Then I fill my table cells:

```
for(let key in d_dict){
            let cell = row.insertCell(-1);
            if(key==='Select'){
                var checkbox_html = d_dict[key];
                cell.innerHTML = checkbox_html;
                console.log(cell);
            }
            else{
                let val = d_dict[key];
                let newText = document.createTextNode(val);
                cell.appendChild(newText);
                console.log(cell);
            }

        }
```

But it shows the text instead of the checkbox.

[image]

Edit:
I did

```
for(k in checkbox_html){
   console.log(checkbox_html[k]);
}
```

and it showed me a bunch of integers:

[image: ints]

What does that mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `createElementFromHTML()` function returns a DOM element object, not a string of HTML:

```
var checkbox_div = createElementFromHTML(cboxHTMLString, div);
```

Because it is a DOM element, you must use the `.appendChild()` method to append it to the cell:

```
if(key==='Select'){
    var checkbox_html = d_dict[key];
    cell.appendChild( checkbox_html );
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing that out!  A bit of a tangent but only the first checkbox can be checked.